# Using jQuery to create a table from the database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to the MVC model and need some help figuring this out.

**PricingList.cshtml**
This page should have a TextBox so you can input a state (ex: AL, OR), a submit button that once clicked will render a table based on the state chosen.

```
model IEnumerable<AtrPricing.MVC.Models.CountyListViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Pricing List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}    

    <form>
        Choose State: <input type="text" id="choosestate" name="choosestate" maxlength="2" autofocus placeholder="State"/>
        <button id="submitstate" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
<div>
//div containing my table headers
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">    
 $('#submitstate').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: { state: $('#choosestate').val() },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#table-pricingList').html(resutl);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });       
</script>
```

**Home Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private VendorRepository repository = new VendorRepository();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult PricingList(string state)
    {
        if (state == null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            var StateList = repository.GetStateList(state);
            return View(state);
        }
    }    
}
```

**GetStateList()**
This is inside "VendorRepository.cs". This code works just fine.

```
public List<CountyListViewModel> GetStateList(string state)
{
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("@State", value: state);

    var query = @"SELECT counties.id
                    , counties.CountyName
                    , counties.Website
                    , counties.Address
                    , counties.City
                    , counties.State
                    , counties.PhonePrimary
                    , counties.PhoneAlt
                    , counties.RecordsOnline
                    , counties.BackToYear
                    , counties.Cost
                FROM
                    counties
                WHERE
                    counties.state = @State;";

    return this.db.Query<CountyListViewModel>(query,parameters).ToList();
}
```

**CountyViewModel**

This contains the **CountyListViewModel** from the previous section.

```
public class EditCountyViewModel
{
    public County county { get; set; }
    public List<County> CountyList { get; set; }
}

public class CountyListViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountyName { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PhonePrimary { get; set; }
    public string PhoneAlt { get; set; }
    public int RecordsOnline { get; set; }
    public int BackToYear { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Right now, once i fill in the textbox with a state (ex: 'al') and click the submit button my url changes from "~/Home/PricingList" to "~/Home/PricingList?choosestate=al". Which is what i think i want. **HOWEVER** this always results in my 'state' variable for **public ActionResult PricingList(string state)** to be 'null'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enter code here`have you modified the route location to include string instead of int if not you might want to trye

like this

```
  public ActionResult PricingList()
    {
        string state;
        if (Request.QueryString["choosestate"] != null)
        {
            state = Request.QueryString["choosestate"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            state = "ALL";
        }
        var StateList = repository.GetStateList(state);
        return View(StateList);
    }
```

Comment: Where should this go? in the CountyViewModels.cs? or inside the PricingList(string state) function inside the HomeController?

Comment: This resulted in an `System.NullReferenceException` error when the `~/Home/PricingList` page is called

Answer (score 0):

If you put id="tableContainer" to your div that is suppose to hold the table you could do something like this. Assuming your data is JSON call this function from the success in your ajax call.

```
function DisplayTable(counties) {
$("#tableContainer").html("");
var table = $("<table/>");

$(counties).each(function () {
    var tr = $("<tr/>");
    $("<td/>", {
        text: this.CountyName
    }).appendTo(tr);
    $("<td/>", {
        text: this.Website
    }).appendTo(tr);
    tr.appendTo(table);
});
$("#tableContainer").append(table);
}
```

Comment: This had no visible change on the output. I still am getting 'null' for my 'state' variable inside the PricingList(). So, for some reason, my `ActionResult PricingList()` is not receiving what is in my textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      public ActionResult PricingList(string state)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(state)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View(repository.GetStateList(state));
        }
    }

        $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: "{'state':'" +  $('#choosestate').val() + "'}"
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#table-pricingList').html(resutl);
                }
            });
```